# Linux/Windows Dualboot: Does it make sense to repartition a whole drive when reinstalling Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, dual-boot, gpt, partition-table

Assumed we have a MS-Windows/Linux dualboot system that works completely fine:

- partitioning scheme: `gpt`
- `sda1`: Windows
- `sda2`: Linux Root
- `sda3`: Linux Home

Unfortunately this installation is pretty aged, so I would like to perform a Linux reinstallation while maintaining the MS-Windows dualboot.

---

**Question:** Does it make sense to repartition/reformat the whole drive and also perform a fresh Windows installation in this case?

---

My thoughts concern about possible, technical `gpt` updates that could provide more stability or similar. My assumption is that the `gpt` system used at the previous time of installation could be based on old `gpt` versions, so there could have been implemented several updates in the meanwhile.

Or do I overthink this whole thing too much and it would be completely nonsense to install everything new, where I actually only want to reinstall Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's relevant to repartition or recreate your drive's partition table. The GPT is only the table, that points out how the disk is divided and how the partitions are identified. The performance itself is dependent on the partition format, not the partition table (for instance ext4 performs better than ext2).

Remember for example how trivial is to convert a partition table. You can convert a MBR disk to GPT with gdisk in an instant, without having to reformat your partitions.